# How can I book a hotel in France for a Schengen visa without paying in advance?

Tags: visas, schengen, france

I want to go to France from DR Congo and I am told that I need a proof of hotel reservation confirmation. When I contacted one of the cheapest hotel, they told me that I need to pay for the number of days which I want to be mentioned in the reservation paper. But it's too expensive: 30days * €35 is too much for me... are there any other ways of booking a hotel for which I won't have to pay a lot?

Comment: Where are you coming from? What is your nationality?

Comment: Generally, the payment policy for hotels varies greatly. You can probably find one that doesn't require payment up-front, but I'm not sure how to search for that on most search engines.

Comment: If you can't afford to pay for the hotel now, how would you be able to pay when the time came to go to France?

Comment: @Gagravarr: It's easy to see how a tight cash flow would lead to that situation.

Comment: (1) One possibility for lowest cost MAY be the [**"Hotel Premiere Class"**](http://www.premiereclasse.com/en)  chain of hotels - located in numerous places across France. Premier they are not. Cheap they are and value for money (in my opinion). (2) If you book via a booking site such as hostels.com, hotels.com, Agoda or similar you usually pay a fee to the booking site and then the full amount to the hotel or hostel on arrival. If you choose a hotel or site that advertises cost-=free cancellations you do not have to pay for any longer than you need. (3) Does it have to be a hotel? Will ...

Comment: ... a hostel do? Does it have to be a room? Will a dormitory do? If you book a dormitory for the full period, what shows on the reservation form? If it just shows that you are booked for however many days that may suit your needs. (4) FWIW hotel premier class can be very convenient for budget travellers. Book in ANY time if they have a spare room. Use a credit card to get access to a room. All rooms have outside doors. TYpically 3 beds (2 bunk + 1) tiny bathroom. Possibly a communal breakfast room with basic breakfast for extra $. If all you want is basic accommodation they are excellent.